# Не активные Bar Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Создал `Tab Bar Controller` после чего, для каждой ветки, создал свой `Navigation Controller`. 
Проблема заключается в том что `UI Bar Button`, не активны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так создаю кнопку

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"filterImage"];
    myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(testMethod:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что у  `Tab Bar Controller` имеется свой верхний бар.
Если прописать ему `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`
То кнопки начинают работать.